# FS80H USB Fingerprint Scanner in Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, usb, hardware, linux

I have a Futronic (model FS80H) USB fingerprint scanner. I am currently trying to get it to work with a Raspberry Pi.

On their website they mention that on Linux it doesn't use any kernel mode driver, but uses libusb to interface with hardware. They also have a GTK and ScanAPI sample (I am yet to find a SDK), but as its normal those are x86 / Intel architecture compiled binaries. So I can't run those on a Pi 3.

Is there any alternate SDK or method to use this scanner with the Pi 3? I am open to Python/C++ or even command line utilities.

Once connected to Pi, the scanner appears as the following device in `lsusb` :

`Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1491:0020 Futronic Technology Co. Ltd. FS81 Fingerprint Scanner Module`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try contacting them directly, and return it if they don't have ARM drivers. There are lots of fingerprint readers with open-source libraries.

Comment: They do have a Android demo for their API (though I don't have android device with USB support to check that). But the compatible devices they mentioned on http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_sdk_linux.html are ARM processor devices. So they have the drivers, but not able to find it.

Comment: then you definitely have to contact them :)

Comment: @JayEye you say many readers exist. Can you point me to one that works over usb for rpi 0?